# WPF Control form resize

Tags: wpf, resize, window

I have two controls on my form, i have two use case

1. When i drag from the right corner, i want to re size the form and all controls should be aligned appropriately
2. When i drag from the right edge, the right side controls should be hidden

I have already tried the Res size mode  as can re size and i can handle the first user scenario.

I have used a View Box property which is enabling the re size of window when i drag and shrink it.

I am not able to find a control that can allow me to re size and hide a portion of the window at two different events

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas for you.

1. You may handle the SizeChanged event for your window.
2. SizeChangedEventArgs has two propertis: HeightChanged, WidthChanged.
3. Maybe you can collapse the viewbox when only Widthchanged is ture.

Update:
After tested, Collapse viewbox will collapse the content in viewbox. So I write code like below to avoid this issue. But It's worked not very well. Just FYI:

```
<Grid>
     <Viewbox>
        <content/>
      </Viewbox>
        <content/>
</Grid>
```